# Zonal Statistics ArcMap 10.4

Tags: arcpy, zonal-statistics, arcgis-10.4

I have a problem using Zonal statistics in python using ArcMap 10.4. This is a completely random error, and I have no idea what to do. 
Some back ground is that I have been running a script doing batch processing work with zonal stats and extracting values etc. and it worked fine for various areas. All of a sudden the zonal statistics stopped working. There is no error, the program just ends abruptly.

I have tried to debug it in many ways (different environmental settings etc.) but here is the core of my problem:

A simple version of the program is as follow:

```
import os

import arcpy

from arcpy import env

from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

from decimal import Decimal

location = "C:/Users/Me/"

shapefile = "C:/Users/Me/My_shapefile.shp"

raster = "//server_location/raster_location/raster_file.tif"

print "Start Zonal"

outZonalStatistics = ZonalStatistics(shapefile, "Valid_ID", raster, "MEAN", "DATA")

print "Done"

print "Saving"

outZonalStatistics.save(location + "mean_zonal")

print "Done"
```

Then the output is as follow:

```
>>> Start Zonal
>>> ================================ RESTART =================================
>>>
```

Thus the program just abruptly ends when Zonal Stats is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. It is a low level problem that I do not understand in full, however just changing the scratch workspace fixes the bug. Perhaps the default scratch workspace has a certain limit that is reached, then it needs to change. Here is a read for more information: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/86027

The code I used is the standard for changing the scratch workspace:

arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:/Users/Me/ArcMap_scratch"

Comment: This matches the clue that it worked for several areas then suddenly stopped working. Good work.